# "NoNodeAvailableExceptionException" thrown by class TransportClient

Tags: java, networking, elasticsearch

I am new to `ElasticSearch v2.3.1` and trying to connect to the `elasticsearch` cluster using `TransportClient`

My code is like:

```
Settings settings = Settings.settingsBuilder().put("cluster.name", "my-cluster").put("client.transport.sniff", true)..put("shield.user", "transport_client_user:user")build();
Client client = TransportClient.builder().addPlugin(ShieldPlugin.class).settings(settings).build().addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 9200)));
GetResponse getResponse = client.prepareGet("megacorp", "employee", "1").get();
```

I have verified the server and it is running fine on the mentioned port (9200).
The indexes are also in place and checked it by querying elasticsearch server directly via `Sense`

The above code throws the following exception on Java End:

```
Exception in thread "main" NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{127.0.0.1}{localhost/127.0.0.1:9200}]]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:290)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:207)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.support.TransportProxyClient.execute(TransportProxyClient.java:55)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.doExecute(TransportClient.java:288)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:359)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:86)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:56)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.get(ActionRequestBuilder.java:64)
    at com.elastic.GET.callMe(GET.java:50)
    at com.elastic.GET.main(GET.java:33)
```

On Elasticsearch server console the exception is:

```
[2016-04-25 16:16:13,488][WARN ][shield.transport.netty   ] [Pete Wisdom] Caught exception while handling client http traffic, closing connection [0x79694953, /127.0.0.1:56521 => /127.0.0.1:9200]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: empty text
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.<init>(HttpVersion.java:89)
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.valueOf(HttpVersion.java:62)
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequestDecoder.createMessage(HttpRequestDecoder.java:75)
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:191)
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:102)
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:500)
```

I have tried changing the port to 9300 as suggested by some posts, but to no avail.

Also I see the same exception on elasticsearch server console when I try to hit 
`https://localhost:9200` 
from the browser.

So may be the transport client is trying to connect to `https://localhost:9200` --is this possible. 
If so, how to get `http://localhost` from new `InetSocketAddress()`

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: have you used any `rest-client` or `curl` Operation to fetch the data from that location?

Comment: Yes, and that too is working fine.

Comment: Is your server and java library version same?

Comment: Yes, I am running both server and client on the same machine - same JVM...